# Ansible Upload large files best practise

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create an Ansible installer machine on AWS to create an auto-install seeding machine for certain application.

One of the steps requires uploading 3 large files around 10GB each into the target machine.

I am using the `copy` module at the moment to move those files to target machines,
from my understanding, the `copy` module is actually utilizing `shutil copy2` underneath, which supposes to be a *fast copy* for python.

But I noticed the `copy` command is actually taking way longer time to upload those binaries vs. I execute the `scp` command manually, I understand there are some commands like md5 checks will take some extra time with overhead.

Is there any other ways / best practice to do efficient large file uploads?

I know the `synchronize` module can be used as it is using `rsync` underneath. But the requirement of installing `rsync` on both sides is not ideal for my scenario.

Any other modules that can be utilized in this case?